# jQuery Input Slider Plugin not functioning properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slider

I am trying to use this plugin here to create a slider on my page: http://egorkhmelev.github.com/jslider/

Unfortunately on my demo page I can't seem to get it to create the slider element properly, and I'm not receiving any javascript errors in the console.

Here is my demo page: http://nathanmarks.ca/drivvy_demo/search.php

I call the slider function in script.js and I'm trying to create it in the 'refine search' box on the page.

I also tried making a blank page with a slider in it and was experiencing the same problem!

I would experience any help, thanks! I don't know what I have done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to create slider from `$("#SliderSingle")` element which is `<input>` tag. You should use `<div id="something"></div>` instead of that.

Comment: This plugin doesn't use divs, it uses the input tag, but now that you mention it I think it may be a conflict with jqueryUI that I have loaded too as they both have slider() functions!!

Comment: Oh. It's totally separate issue. Anyway, when you call `slider()` on a div, a slider does appear.

Comment: it can be a conflict, i don`t know how its possible to create a slider from input tag, usually the value of slider is written in the input!!

Comment: Yeah, I wanted the other plugin though so I downloaded another build of jqueryUI without the slider widget and now it works fine!

Comment: If you check the example page of the plugin I linked on github, it uses input tags not divs